# Skype for Business | What is an "AIR ID" in SFB terminology?

Tags: chatbot, skype-for-business

I intend to use it while preparing an SFB chatbot and during its integration with SFB, I've been asked to enter "Application's AIR ID", which I'm not sure what exactly is it?

PS: I tried googling, but no luck.

Answer (score 0):

I've not heard the term `AIR` specifically, but what it's referring to is the **[`Microsoft App ID`](https://docs.botframework.com/en-us/azure-bot-service/manage/appid-password/)** (which is also sometimes known as a `Bot ID`).

You would integrate it into the following:

```
<div class="skype-button bubble" data-bot-id="YOUR_BOT_ID"></div>
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks, @obsidian-age. Will check this out if it's helpful.